# Reintentar prueba de conexión android

Tags: java, android

Intento hacer una app que al iniciarse compruebe si hay conexión a internet. En caso afirmativo lleve a una nueva actividad que en un futuro será una pantalla de login, y en caso negativo que aparezca un botón para reintentar. La primera opción funciona bien, pero cuando no tengo conexión aparece el botón, le activo el wifi y los datos móviles y aprieto el botón pero me sigue diciendo que no tengo conexión. Alguna idea?

```
    public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView texto;
    ImageButton restart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        texto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        restart = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        restart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        restart.setEnabled(false);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do something after 3s
                isNetworkAvailable();
            }
        }, 3000);

    }

    private void isNetworkAvailable() {
        boolean connected = false;
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            //we are connected to a network
            connected = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            connected = false;
            texto.setText("No tienes internetes compañero");
            restart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            restart.setEnabled(true);

        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        if(v.getId()==R.id.imageButton){
            isNetworkAvailable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cual es el problema que no detecta correctamente si no tienes conexión? o  que no aparece el botón?

Comment: Que no detecta correctamente la conectividad al re-intentar la conexión usando el botón